# react state undefined after refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

So I'm building a react app and, initially, my data renders to the page correctly but when I click the refresh button I get this error - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'image'). Can someone please help me here?

```
import "./Explore.css";
const postsPerLoad = 6;
let arrayForHoldingPosts = [];

function Explore(props) {
  const { posts } = props;
  const [newestMetaPost, setNewestMetaPost] = useState([]);
  const [allPosts, setAllPosts] = useState([]);
  const [nextPosts, setNextPosts] = useState(6);
  const { DateTime } = require("luxon");

  const loopWithSlice = (start, end) => {
    const metaPosts = posts.filter(post => post.category === 'Meta');
    const latestMetaPost = metaPosts.sort((b, a) => a.id - b.id)[0];
    const filteredMetaPosts = posts.filter(post => post.id !== latestMetaPost.id);
    const slicedPosts = filteredMetaPosts.reverse().slice(start, end);
    arrayForHoldingPosts = [...arrayForHoldingPosts, ...slicedPosts];
    setAllPosts(arrayForHoldingPosts);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    arrayForHoldingPosts = [];
    let metaPosts = posts.filter(post => post.category === 'Meta');
    let latestMetaPost = metaPosts.sort((b, a) => a.id - b.id)[0];
    setNewestMetaPost(latestMetaPost);

    loopWithSlice(0, postsPerLoad);
  }, [])

  console.log(newestMetaPost)

  const handleShowMorePosts = () => {
    loopWithSlice(nextPosts, nextPosts + postsPerLoad);
    setNextPosts(nextPosts + postsPerLoad);
  };

  return (
    <div >
      <img class="explore-image" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/tylerwashington98/image/upload/v1636154827/Meta-Minds/meta_vmqfci.jpg" alt="banner image"></img>
      <div class="latest-and-all-posts-main-div">
        <div class="latest-post-div">
          <img class="latest-post-image" src={newestMetaPost.image} alt={newestMetaPost.title} ></img>
          <div class="latest-post-details-div">
            <div class="latest-post-details-background-div"></div>
            <div class="latest-post-details-text-div">
              <h4 class="latest-post-details-date-and-category-text-div">
                <h6 class="latest-post-details-date text"> {DateTime.now().toLocaleString(DateTime.DATE_MED)}</h6>
                <img class="meta-logo" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/tylerwashington98/image/upload/v1636143053/Meta-Minds/2d4b6fe46ee740998e2e0f51bbbd3496_esrod4.png" alt="Meta Minds Logo"></img>
                <h1 class="latest-post-details-category text">{newestMetaPost.category}</h1>
              </h4>
              <p class="latest-post-details-title text">{newestMetaPost.title}</p>
              <p class="latest-post-details-subtitle text subtitle">{newestMetaPost.subtitle}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I believe lines 2 through 4  in the useEffect function is what's giving me problems but I'm not sure how to change it. line 5 in the return is where this error occurs

Comment: In your second image tag you are trying to set "newestMetaPost.image" as if it's an object, but newestMetaPost is an array.

Comment: Okay thanks, so how would I change it?

Comment: it looks for me that the error is not in this piece of code, but somewhere else

Comment: really? in my inpsector tools it says the errors are on lines 5 , 12 , 14 and 15 in the return.